# Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, pdo

```
        <?php
                    $busca = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE `TIPO` = 2 AND `ESTADO` = :s ORDER BY `nESTRELAS` DESC, `NOME` ASC;");
                    $busca->bindValue(":s", 10);
                    $busca->execute();
                    $linha = $busca->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                    foreach($linha as $listar) {

                        echo "<li><a href='perfil.php' title='aqui'>$listar-NOME</a></li>";
                    }

        ?>
```

I don't understand because i recieve "could not be converted to string"

Comment: Is that a typo here, `$listar-NOME`? Should be `$listar->NOME`. I'd also concatenate that.

Comment: thanks... I had not seen the lack of ">"

Comment: Did that resolve it?

Comment: No thanks, i got it :)

Answer (score 0):

before foreach just add this `echo "<pre>"; print_r($linha);` if you are getting a array then get as like that `$linha['NOME'];` if you are getting a object then use like that `$linha->NOME;` please try this....